# Cannot mock Props.navgation.navigate in React Native Navigation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I have this function _navigateLogin, something like this

```
export const _navigateLogin = (props: Props): () => void => () => {
  props.navigation.navigate(UnathorizedRoutes.LoginEmailPasswordPage);
};
```

and props type is like this

```
export type NavigationProps = NativeStackScreenProps<UnauthorizedStackParams,
UnauthorizedRoutes.IntroductionPage>

export type Props = NavigationProps;
```

My function works correctly, but when I tried to test. I can't find the best way to mock my function.

I tried to mock like this

```
const mockRoute = {
  key: 'key',
  name: UnathorizedRoutes.IntroductionPage
};

const mockProps = {
  navigation: {
    addListener: jest.fn(),
    canGoBack: jest.fn(),
    dispatch: jest.fn(),
    goBack: jest.fn(),
    isFocused: jest.fn(),
    setParams: jest.fn(),
    setOptions: jest.fn(),
    reset: jest.fn(),
    getId: jest.fn(),
    getParent: jest.fn(),
    getState: jest.fn(),
    jumpTo: jest.fn(),
    navigate: jest.fn(),
    removeListener: jest.fn()
  },
  route: mockRoute
};
```

but when it try to add it to `_navigateLogin(mockProps)` it's always have error like this

```
Argument of type '{
  navigation: {
    addListener: jest.Mock<any, any, any>;
    canGoBack: jest.Mock<any, any, any>;
    dispatch: jest.Mock<any, any, any>;
    goBack: jest.Mock<any, any, any>;
    ...9 more...;
    removeListener: jest.Mock<...>;
  };
  route: {
    ...;
  };
}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationProps'. 

Types of property 'navigation' are incompatible.

Type '{
  addListener: jest.Mock<any, any, any>;
  canGoBack: jest.Mock<any, any, any>;
  dispatch: jest.Mock<any, any, any>;
  goBack: jest.Mock<any, any, any>;
  isFocused: jest.Mock<...>;
  ...8 more...;
  removeListener: jest.Mock<...>;
}' is not assignable to type 
'NativeStackNavigationProp<UnauthorizedStackParams, UnauthorizedRoutes.IntroductionPage, undefined>'.

Type '{
  addListener: Mock<any, any, any>;
  canGoBack: Mock<any, any, any>;
  dispatch: Mock<any, any, any>;
  goBack: Mock<any, any, any>;
  isFocused: Mock<any, any, any>;
  ...8 more...;
  removeListener: Mock<...>;
} is missing the following properties from type 
'StackActionHelpers<UnauthorizedStackParams>': replace, push, pop, popToTop`
```

I don't know how to fix and find the best way to mock my function, can someone help me to find the best way to mock it?